# ScrollView between two Layouts in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I want to put a scrollView between two Layout and put all 3 layout in 1 constraintLayout as below :

```
<ConstraintLayout>
  <LinearLayout> // Title
  <ScrollView>
  <RelativeLayout> // Buttons
<ConstraintLayout>
```

this in my Layout XML code :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/registerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:context="momtaz.moshaver_yar.StudentFragment_Register">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/registerStudentTitleTxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="ثبت نام دانش آموز"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/registerStudentScroll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/registerStudentBtn"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/regstscrollayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerNameLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@id/regStNameEdit"
                    android:text="نام و نام خانوادگی :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStNameEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerBirthDateLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="تاریخ تولد :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerBirthDateTxt"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textDirection="rtl"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:text="10/08/1369" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/registerBirthDateBtn"
                    android:layout_width="28dp"
                    android:layout_height="28dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/datebtnselector" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerGenderLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="جنسیت :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/registerGenderBoy"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:button="@drawable/radiobtnselector"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=" پسر"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/registerGenderGirl"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:button="@drawable/radiobtnselector"
                        android:text=" دختر"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </RadioGroup>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerMCodeLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="کد ملی :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStMCodeEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerMobileLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@+id/regStPhoneEdit"
                    android:text="شماره تماس :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStMobileEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerPhoneLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="شماره تماس منزل :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStPhoneEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerStGradeLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="پایه تحصیلی :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStGradeEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerAdviserLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@id/regStAdviserEdit"
                    android:text="کد مشاور :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/regStAdviserEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerAdviserNameLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@id/regStNameEdit"
                    android:text="نام مشاور :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/regStAdviserNameTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerStUNameLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@id/regStUNameEdit"
                    android:text="نام کاربری :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStUNameEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerStUPassLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@id/regStUPassEdit"
                    android:text="رمز عبور :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStUPassEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerStUPass2Label"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@id/regStUPass2Edit"
                    android:text="تکرار رمز عبور :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStUPass2Edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/registerStudentBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/regStPostBtn"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btnselector"
            android:text="ثبت"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/regStProgressImg"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/regStPostBtn"
            android:background="@drawable/loading_animate" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/regStCancelBtn"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btnselector"
            android:text="انصراف"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have created this connections of constraintLayout :

- Top of TitleLayout to Top of Parent
- Top of ScrollView to Bottom of TitleLayout
- Bottom of ScrollView to Top of ButtonLayout
- Bottom of ButtonLayout to Bottom of Parent
- Right and Left of All Layouts to Right and Left of Parent

There is no problem is Design-View but when I test it in GenyMotion emulator, the ButtonLayout doesn't show, it seems that the Height of ScrollView is larger than the space between bottom of TitleView and top of ButtonLayout, I can't find out whats going wrong !

I have tested NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView or RelativeLayout instead of ConstraintLayout but the problem not solved

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you put the `LinearLayout`, `ScrollView` and the `RelativeLayout` in a vertical chain to keep them properly constrained to each other and to prevent them from overlapping. In order to create the chain you need to add a couple additional constraints:

- bottom of TitleLayout to top of ScrollView
- top of ButtonLayout to bottom of ScrollView

Please note that I only added two additional constraints to create a chain and did not change anything else or did not fix any other small problems with the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/registerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:context="momtaz.moshaver_yar.StudentFragment_Register">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/registerStudentScroll"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/registerStudentTitleTxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="ثبت نام دانش آموز"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/registerStudentScroll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/registerStudentBtn"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/regstscrollayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerNameLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@id/regStNameEdit"
                    android:text="نام و نام خانوادگی :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStNameEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerBirthDateLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="تاریخ تولد :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerBirthDateTxt"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textDirection="rtl"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    tools:text="10/08/1369" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/registerBirthDateBtn"
                    android:layout_width="28dp"
                    android:layout_height="28dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/datebtnselector" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerGenderLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="جنسیت :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/registerGenderBoy"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:button="@drawable/radiobtnselector"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=" پسر"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/registerGenderGirl"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:button="@drawable/radiobtnselector"
                        android:text=" دختر"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </RadioGroup>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerMCodeLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="کد ملی :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStMCodeEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerMobileLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@+id/regStPhoneEdit"
                    android:text="شماره تماس :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStMobileEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerPhoneLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="شماره تماس منزل :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStPhoneEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerStGradeLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="پایه تحصیلی :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStGradeEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerAdviserLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@id/regStAdviserEdit"
                    android:text="کد مشاور :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/regStAdviserEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerAdviserNameLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@id/regStNameEdit"
                    android:text="نام مشاور :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/regStAdviserNameTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerStUNameLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@id/regStUNameEdit"
                    android:text="نام کاربری :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStUNameEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerStUPassLabel"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@id/regStUPassEdit"
                    android:text="رمز عبور :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStUPassEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/registerStUPass2Label"
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:labelFor="@id/regStUPass2Edit"
                    android:text="تکرار رمز عبور :"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/regStUPass2Edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/editselector"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/registerStudentBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/registerStudentScroll"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/regStPostBtn"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btnselector"
            android:text="ثبت"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/regStProgressImg"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/regStPostBtn"
            android:background="@drawable/loading_animate" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/regStCancelBtn"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btnselector"
            android:text="انصراف"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It looks fine on my device, both top and bottom views are showing and the scrollview in the middle is scrollable if there are many elements. Could you perhaps add a screenshot of what your screen looks like?

Comment: Update my answer with the XML.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not worked in Genymotion ( Android 5 and 7 ) and BlueStacks. I am using this layout in a fragment that inflates it in a FrameLayout in MainActivity